# spChFIDs() on level 1 or higher map-files

Tags: r, graphics, maps

Hopefully (one of) the last question on map-files.

Why is this not working, and how would I do that right?

```
load(url('http://gadm.org/data/rda/CUB_adm1.RData'))
CUB <- gadm
CUB <- spChFIDs(CUB, paste("CUB", rownames(CUB), sep = "_"))
```

Thank you very much!!!

seems to work with row.names()

```
load(url('http://gadm.org/data/rda/CUB_adm1.RData'))
CUB <- gadm
CUB <- spChFIDs(CUB, paste("CUB", row.names(CUB), sep = "_"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is apparent once one reads the help for `?row.names()` and `?rownames()`.

The `rownames()` function only knows something about matrix-like objects, and `CUB` is not one of those, hence it doesn't have row names that `rownames()` can find:

```
> rownames(CUB)
NULL
```

`row.names()` is different, it is an S3 generic function and that means package authors can write methods for specific types of objects such that the row names of those objects can be extracted.

Here is a list of the methods available for `row.names()` in my current session, with the `sp` package loaded:

```
> methods(row.names)
 [1] row.names.data.frame               
 [2] row.names.default                  
 [3] row.names.SpatialGrid*             
 [4] row.names.SpatialGridDataFrame*    
 [5] row.names.SpatialLines*            
 [6] row.names.SpatialLinesDataFrame*   
 [7] row.names.SpatialPixels*           
 [8] row.names.SpatialPoints*           
 [9] row.names.SpatialPointsDataFrame*  
[10] row.names.SpatialPolygons*         
[11] row.names.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame*

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

The class of the object `CUB` is:

```
> class(CUB)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

So what is happening is that the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` method of the `row.names()` function is being used and it knows where to find the required row names.

Comment: @Marcel no probs. Glad the answer helped.